# WordPress - wp-image-NUMBER won't add alt, width and height on some WordPress websites?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

When I add `size-full wp-image-IMAGE_ID` to an `img` tag, it adds `alt`, `width`, and `height` on some WordPress sites like below:

[image: Works]

But some WordPress sites won't apply mentioned attributes and the result is:

[image: DoesntWork]

How can I fix it to add alt, width, and alt to images?

Comment: Do they have the same version?

Comment: I checked it now. The one that is working is `5.7` and the one that doesn't is `5.3.6`. How to make the `5.3.6` work?

Comment: Does https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/330599/200813 solve the issue?

Comment: No, because I want to handle it in the front-end using jQuery.